# Empty list returned when accessing automl leader via @leader@model

Tags: r, h2o, automl

Running `h2o.automl()` returns a single model in leaderboard; however, when trying to access the actual model via `@leader@model`, the following error ensues:

> Error in is.H2OFrame(x) : trying to get slot "metrics" from an object
>   of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots

As well, when calling `h2o.predict()` on the leader model, got the error message:

> Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion,
>   urlSuffix = page,  : ERROR MESSAGE: Object 'dummy' not found in
>   function: predict for argument: model

Model was run in the same session using `h2o` `v3.20.0.2` in `R`.

Comment: How big is your training set?  I assume you ran for the default time period of 3600 seconds (1 hour)?

Comment: The training set has dimensions of 310 x 119886, and I ran it for 3600 seconds indeed. I'll try to extend that number and see.

Answer (score 4):

I think what's happening is that you're not able to train a single model in one hour, so when you try to collect the leader model, it's trying to grab an incomplete model and you get an error.  You don't have very many rows, but you have a really large number of columns.

Since it's hard to predict how long the model training will take, I'd use the `max_models` argument instead of limiting by time.  Since AutoML will stop when it reaches the first of `max_models` or `max_runtime_secs`, I'd set `max_runtime_secs` to a very large number (e.g. 999999999) and then set `max_models = 10` or whatever number you like.

Second, since you have very wide data, I'd recommend turning off the Random Forests and GBM models, and leaving the GLM and Deep Learning models.  To do that, set `exclude_algos = c("DRF", "GBM")`.  It will take a really long time to train tree-based models on 120k columns.

Another good option to consider is to first apply [PCA](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/pca.html) or [GLRM](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glrm.html) to your data to reduce the dimensionality to <500 columns and then you can include the tree-based models in the AutoML run.

Comment: @KingJulien Why are you commenting here for another issue? Your comment is not related to this question or my answer.  This is the second issue you've posted on, please do not do this.

Comment: I wanted your help that's why I commented here. I will delete my comment. Thanks

Comment: Hi @ErinLeDell, I am getting the same error but on a significantly smaller data set. My feature set is 10k rows x 20 columns. I'm trying to train a multi class classifier with `balance_classes = TRUE` with `stopping_metric = TRUE` and `sort_metric = TRUE`. I have also tried your trick of setting `max_runtime_secs` to a large value and setting `max_models`. My H2O version is 3.23.0.4532. I'm guessing balance_classes and multi class don't play nice? Or is there something else that might be going on? Thanks very much!

Comment: @elvikingo Both `stopping_metric` and `sort_metric` take a string as a value, they are not boolean. You are using a nightly version (can you re-try on the stable version 3.22?).  If you can post a reproducible example on Stack Overflow or even better, file a JIRA ticket with the example, https://0xdata.atlassian.net/projects/PUBDEV, that would be super helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: @ErinLeDell thanks for your response, Erin. I'm sorry I made a mistake while writing that comment. I definitely had `stopping_metric = "AUC"` and not TRUE. I changed to the stable version 3.22.1.6 and it seems to be working fine. Would you still like me to file a ticket for the nightly version?

Comment: @elvikingo If you have a reproducible example (maybe using the iris dataset for example), then yes, it would be great to file a JIRA ticket, thank you!